# Localizing Dates From Remote Server

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm storing all dates on my server as UTC.  I fetch this data to my app via JSON and am successfully parsing these dates.  How should I localize the dates in Objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `NSDateFormatter` it has build in formatting and can display based on local.